# php 5.5 and Call time pass by reference has been removed

Tags: php

i have this code

```
$ITOG=array();
      $ex=explode("\n",$TEXT);
         foreach ($ex as $line)
          {
           if (strlen($line)<10){continue;}

           if (($line[0]=='#') || ($line[0]=='/' && $line[1]=='/'))  {continue;}

            $id=sizeof($ITOG);

            $ITOG[$id]['_raw']=$line;

            $this->analyze($id,&$ITOG);
          }
```

i show some people said that i must remove &$ and place $
yes its correct and it dosent show error
but my script not work in php 5.5 but it work in php 5.2

Comment: how is the signature of `analyze` function?

Comment: Then you need to change your code not to rely on calltime-pass-by-reference.

Comment: Remove `&` from call time and inside your `analyze()` method place the `&` to the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change the definition of your `analyze` function so that it **always** takes parameter 2 by reference. The idea behind this is that a function should do the same thing on its data every time. It shouldn't depend on whether you decide to pass a copy of the variable (pass-by-value, without a `&`) or a pointer to the variable itself (pass-by-reference, with a `&`).

You should change your function from something like this:

```
public function analyze($id, $something) {
```

to something like this:

```
public function analyze($id, &$something) {
```

By making it define-time pass-by-reference, you can then remove the `&` from your call:

```
$this->analyze($id, $ITOG);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference still exists in PHP, but it has been removed at call time. This means that the following code:

```
function foo($val){
   // ...
}

foo(&$val);
```

must be refactored, because passing by reference in the call is not supported anymore.
It must be changed to the following:

```
function foo(&$val){
   // ...
}

foo($val);
```

In your case, you must look for the definition of the `analyze` function, and add the `&` in front of the second parameter, **in the function definition**, and remove it at call time. It should look something like:

```
function analyze($id, &$ITOG){ // ...

...

$this->analyze($id, $ITOG);
```

Answer (score 0):

This means there is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference.

As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.